# Determine the time a video will play

Tags: javascript, youtube

I would like to know how YouTube determine how long a video is.Like how do i determine if a video is 1 minute long?
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to get the duration of a video file using JS, or through some other means? Or do you want to get the duration of a given YouTube video?

Comment: Any means that can help me find the duration of a video .Not necessarily YouTube videos

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, for operations on video files, you'd use `ffmpeg`. Check out [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/650291/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds) for use cases.

Here's a sample command from that question, using `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```